# Child goroutine is not stopped after its parent gorutine exits

Tags: go

I have this code:

```golang
func sleep(d time.Duration, ch chan<- int) {
    fmt.Println("Sleeping...")
    time.Sleep(d)
    fmt.Println("Awake...")
    ch <- 0
}

func parent(ctx context.Context) int {
    ch := make(chan int, 1)

    go sleep(3*time.Second, ch)

    select {
    case <-ctx.Done():
        return 1
    case <-ch:
        return 0
    }
}

func app(wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer wg.Done()

    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 2*time.Second)
    defer cancel()

    res := parent(ctx)

    fmt.Println(res)
}

func main() {

    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(1)

    go app(&wg)

    wg.Wait()

    time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)
}
```

In this example, I have a `ctx` with 2 seconds timeout.
It takes 3 seconds for `childFunc` to end its process.
After 2 seconds the `parent` func returns 1 because of `case <-ctx.Done()`.
But in the main thread I sleep for 2 more seconds and I see the `childFund` hasn't exited and is continuing its process and the `Awake...` will be printed.
Why `childFunc` doesn't exit when its parent goroutine finishes?

Here is the output:

```
Sleeping...
1
Awake...
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you're asking why a goroutine doesn't exit when the goroutine that created it exits. Except for the main goroutine (which when it exits, the whole program including all goroutines exit), goroutines are independent when they launch -- they don't have a "parent" and there's no way to stop them from outside, including termination of the goroutine that launched them. If you want a goroutine to be killable then you have to code it yourself, for example by returning from the goroutine when the passed-in context is cancelled.

Comment: So in this case it's considered a goroutine leak? Because the work is done but goroutine is still working

Comment: And also no resource will be freed.